# How many ways are there to distribute $7$ (identical) apples, $6$ oranges and $7$ pears among $3$ without restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to distribute $7$ (identical) apples, $6$ oranges and $7$ pears among $3$ without restrictions?

Here is my solution below, is this the correct method? If not how can I fix it? thanks!

Using stars and bars on each fruit,

Apples,

$\dbinom{7+3-1}{3-1} = \dbinom{9}{2} = 36$

Oranges,

$\dbinom{6+3-1}{3-1} = \dbinom{8}{2} = 28 $

Pears,

$\dbinom{7+3-1}{3-1} = \dbinom{9}{2} = 36$

Then adding these cases together would give the total ways.

Comment: Why are you posting the same problem over again?  All you have done is to try to pass off my calculation as your own (you botched it, by the way).

Comment: this is without restirctions, I guess I have done it incorrect

Comment: In the prior example, did I add the cases together?

Comment: You should be multiplying rather than adding.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig then it would be correct?

Comment: @fr14 Yes, it would.

Comment: awesome thanks, but this isn't a duplicate of the question, its another part to it